# Creating a reusable function for deleting/confirming using callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

i'm not sure if this question has been asked before, i did check but i'm not sure how to actually search for it tbh.

I want to create a reusable function for deleting, confirming based on user decision. I created this simple function to edit element data with object values but i'm not able to run the callback that was set in the first function.

Or maybe it's even possible to somehow return a bool from that function based on user's decision?

Here's the logical example of what i want to achieve

```
function run(options, cb){
   if(options['success']){
      cb();
   }
}

var options = {success: true};
var cbarray = new Array('id', 'token');

//calling the function and setting the callback
run(options, function(cbarray){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'blabla',
       type: 'post',
       data: {id: cbarray[0], token: cbarray[1]},
       success: function(resp){
          console.log(resp);
       }, error: function(resp){
          console.log(resp);
       }
    });
});
```

It's kinda hard to explain so i created this jsfiddle with my own code
https://jsfiddle.net/43zrqkvm/7/

Maybe i should actually use promises for that? I haven't yet had time to learn promises but maybe i should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you defining callback function you'r requesting argument that will be used in function body (in you'r case in ajax options) but in Run function you do not passing it

it must look like this

```
function run(options,arg, cb){
       if(options['success']){
          cb(arg);
       }
    }

    var options = {success: true};
    var cbarray = new Array('id', 'token');

    //calling the function and setting the callback
    run(options,cbarray, function(arg){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'blabla',
           type: 'post',
           data: {id: arg[0], token: arg[1]},
           success: function(resp){
              console.log(resp);
           }, error: function(resp){
              console.log(resp);
           }
        });
    });
```

Comment: And it worked, thank you for helping me out. I didn't know it would be that easy :)